# OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied. Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: python, pygame

I was following a tutorial and got stuck here. When I ran the same code for the first time, It went well. But from the second time, it shows error in the same code. I restarted my computer and then it ran once and from the second time, it again shows error.

#THE CODE:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import sys

server = "192.168.0.102"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2)
print("Waiting for a connection , Server Started")


def read_pos(str):
    str = str.split(",")
    return int(str[0]), int(str[1])


def make_pos(tup):
    return str(tup[0]) + "," + str(tup[1])


pos = [(0, 0), (100, 100)]


def threaded_client(conn, player):
    conn.send(str.encode(make_pos(pos[player])))
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = read_pos(conn.recv(2048).decode())
            pos[player] = data

            if not data:
                print("Disconnected")
                break
            else:
                if player == 1:
                    reply = pos[0]
                else:
                    reply = pos[1]

                print("Received : ", data)
                print("Sending: ", reply)

            conn.sendall(str.encode(make_pos(reply)))

        except:
            break

    print("Lost Connection")
    conn.close()


currentPlayer = 0
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to : ", addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, currentPlayer))
    currentPlayer += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different IP address. The code worked correctly when I used `127.0.0.1` which is the local machine.

```
server = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5555
```